# How should I visualize errors that can be on either size of mean

Tags: data-visualization, error

I'm building an app to help players improve the accuracy of their shots in pool (pocket billiards).  Someone might miss shots to either side of the centerline (overcut or undercut), and that's shown on a scatterplot as positive or negative degrees. I want to overlay the scatterplot with a line of moving average error to show progression.

[image: Sample scatterplot]

Naively plotting a moving average won't produce good results because a player who misses wildly on either side will have an average close to zero even though they are very inaccurate.

Ideally, I'd want the visualization to show some sort of moving average of the magnitude of error as well as the side the player tends to miss on.

Comment: could try decomposing the misses into bias and variance

Comment: @JohnMadden so if I understand correctly, it would look something like an area chart with the area representing variance or stddev of recent values, with a line representing the recent mean.  So someone who consistently hits the wrong spot would have a thin error area around the value they hit, and someone who is wild but centered around 0 will have a "mean" line near the x axis with a big error area around it?

Comment: that sounds pretty cool to me

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to visualize the residual variance of the shots over time.  You can model them and compute the formal residuals of the model and then use something use something like the square root of the absolute value of the residual, but that's probably not going to be intuitive / useful for the typical pool player who probably isn't a statistician.  You want to have a plot that is appropriate for your audience.

Since you are using degrees, I would simply plot the absolute value of the degrees on the Y-axis and the time or shot number on the X-axis.  If you want to get fancy for people, you might get away with overlaying a LOWESS fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it really solves the essence of what I'm looking for. Simply plotting the absolute value of degrees isn't correct because the side they miss the shot on is important information.  A simple scatterplot also makes it hard to know if someone is getting better over time.

Comment: @VinayPai, "better over time" would mean that the distance from the target is decreasing.  So the vertical scatter would get lower as you moved to the right across the plot.

Comment: Yes but that's not exactly easy to see from a scatter plot.

Comment: @VinayPai, a reliable change would be visible, especially with a LOWESS fit overlaid.